# HABTM Error - Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Could not find table 'groups_users'

```
<% for group in @groups %>
  <%= check_box_tag "user[group_ids][]", group.id, @user.groups.include?(group) %>
  <%= group.description %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Please provide more information, the Group and User model would be a great start.. It just sounds like you haven't created the `groups_users` table in a migration. Something like `create_table :groups_users, :id => false do |s| s.integer :user_id; s.integer :group_id; end` but we can't tell until we know more

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using a habtm relationship, you need to create the join table. This is a simple table which stores the relationship by referring to each table via foreign key.

```
rails g migration create_groups_users_table

class CreateGroupUsersTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :groups_users, :id => false do |t|
      t.integer :group_id
      t.integer :user_id
    end
  end
end

rake db:migrate
```

Note that the above is for rails 3.1, as it uses the change method. Change to down and up respectively when using rails 3 or lower.

After running the migration, it should work.

Comment: I've done everything you've said the error has gone. But now when i do the GroupsUsers.all inside the rails console it gives me an empty table. Why is this happening

Comment: @Djj There is no GroupUsers model, it's a simple HABTM relationship, which doesn't create a join model. So you would only use `user.groups` or `group.users`. If you want a join model you need a `has_many :though =>` relationship

Comment: Take a look at the guide on active record associations http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html. I generally like to use has_many :through when I can, so I have more control.